# LoadLibrary fails in WCF when changed from IIS Express to Local IIS in VS 2013

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, iis, loadlibrary

I have a WCF service with wsHttpBinding that loads a C++ dll (that has its own dependencies, like CUDA) that works great when hosted via IIS Express. When I switch it to Local IIS in the project properties the

```
LoadLibrary function fails with error 126.
```

I have moved every dll that lives in system32 to the inetsrv (tried System32/inetsrv and sysWOW64/inetsrv) directory (I know it is not the best way, but I wanted to know if that was the issue) but that that did not fix the problem.

The dll I am trying to load is not in either of those directories (never has been) and I give LoadLibrary the path to the dll (i.e. "C:\path\to\file.dll") which, like I said, works great in IIS Express but fails with error 126 in Local IIS.

I have made it so the Users group has full permissions of the directory containing the dll as well (as I believe the IIS Worker processes operate with Users group permissions) but that did not help me either.

Any help would be appreciated! If I am missing some information above let me know and I can get what is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Running IIS Express make use of your login account which surely will work for you have the rights to load the dll. Using IIS your service is running under whatever the account is for the application pool that your service is assigned to. Check that the application pool account has sufficient rights to load the dll.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne I have checked that, and even when changing the identity to LocalSystem (which [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx) tells me should have all the needed permissions) I am getting the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Due to the change in user (IIS app pool having LocalSystem) identity, and a dependency installed as my user (the account I log in with) I had to add the path for that dependency to the System's "path" environment variable.